# Brownian motion where the parameter is a function of $t$

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

i have a question about this exercise:

> Let $f\in L^2[0,t]$ $ \forall t\geq0 $, e $\forall t\geq0$ let
> $a(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f^2(u)du$ and $Y_t=B_{a(t)}$, where B is a continous
> $(F_t)_{t\geq0}$-brownian motion. Show that $Y_t$ is a
> $(F_{a(t)})_{t\geq0}$-brownian motion.

I'm wondering what i have to prove. Isn't it obvious because $B$ is a brownian motion?

Comment: For me it's not a BM since $Var(Y_t)$ is not $t$.

Comment: I don't really see what there is to learn here to be honest; the point seems to just be that if you parametrize by $a(t)$ instead of $t$ then you have a Brownian motion but that's pretty vacuous.